# How to check if the user is already logged in with the OneDrive SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, onedrive

What is the proper way for doing this? Should I use the `expires` property in the `LiveConnectSession` class?

Basically, what I want to do is check if the users is already logged in when I am initializing the user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would check to see if the `LiveConnectSession` is `nil`. The `expires` property should be used to see if you need to get a new `accessToken`. But if you are able to read any of these properties, the user is signed in, however the state of their authentication

This page has sample code for signing in a user and checking if a user is signed in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631822.aspx

Comment: In my case when I terminate the application after logging in with LiveSDK. And again start the application, my session returns nil value. So the sign in pop up opens again which is very annoying , how to solve this?